# The game of 23 matches in SWIPROLOG

Tags: prolog

I tried to make the 23 matches game in SWIPROLOG (compiled here : https://swish.swi-prolog.org/).

What does this game represent?
There are 23 matches on the table. There are two players and each of them has to take a few matches from the table.
matches. Each player is allowed to take 1, 2, or 3 matches. The player who takes the last but one match loses the game.

I have implemented this as a game against the computer (once the computer chooses, once the user chooses, by entering the number of matches on the keyboard). It chooses the number of matches by a special strategy, in such a way, as to make the user lose, i.e. pick up matches in such a way, as to force the user to choose the penultimate match and lose. The 2 make choices until one of them loses.

That's pretty much what I managed to implement:

```
% Start game with 23 matches and computer as first player
joc :- joc(23, calculator, in_progress).

% Player's turn
joc(N, player, State) :-
    nl,
    write('There are '), write(N), write(' matches on the table.'), nl,
    (State == finished ->
        write('The game has ended.'), nl
    ;
        write('It is your turn. '), nl,
        read(M),
        (valid_move(M, N) ->
            N1 is N - M,
            write('You chose '), write(M), write(' matches.'), nl,
            (N1 =< 1 ->
                write('The game has ended. You '), (State == won -> write('won!'), nl ; write('lost!'), nl),
                joc(N1, calculator, finished)
            ;
                joc(N1, calculator, in_progress)
            )
        ;
            write('Invalid move. Please try again.'), nl,
            joc(N, player, State)
        )
    ).

% Computer's turn
joc(N, calculator, State) :-
    nl,
    write('There are '), write(N), write(' matches on the table.'), nl,
    (State == finished ->
        write('The game has ended.'), nl
    ;
        write('It is the computer\'s turn. '), nl,
        optimal_move(N, M),
        N1 is N - M,
        write('The computer chose '), write(M), write(' matches.'), nl,
        (N1 =< 1 ->
            write('The game has ended. The computer '), (State == won -> write('won!'), nl ; write('lost!'), nl),
            joc(N1, player, finished)
        ;
            joc(N1, player, in_progress)
        )
    ).

% Check if move is valid (between 1 and 3 matches, and not more than available matches)
valid_move(M, N) :-
    M >= 1,
    M =< 3,
    M =< N.

% Calculate computer's optimal move
optimal_move(N, M) :-
    X is N mod 4,
    (X > 1 -> M is min(X-1, 3) ; M is max(min(N-2, 3), 1)).
```

The problem in this code, is strategy. I could not identify a strategy, in which the computer would always win.
Here's an example.
If there are 3 matches on the table and it is the computer's turn to pick, it picks 2 and thus loses, while it should pick 1 and the user loses.

My question : is it possible to identify a more efficient startegy, in which the calcualtor would always win(or almost always?) If so, I would be grateful for suggestions, and if possible, code. I'm a beginner in prologue, maybe something will escape me.

Comment: If it isn't part of an optimal strategy, what is `optimal_move` for?

Comment: @ScottHunter This is the strategy I developed, but it is not the most successful

Comment: If there are 3 matches, and the computer takes 2, doesn't that force the opponent to choose the last match, so that the computer wins?

Comment: Strategy outline at: https://gamesdb.launchbox-app.com/games/details/86411-23-matches-creative-computing-software

Comment: @ScottHunter No. If there are 3 on the table, and the computer takes 2, it means that he actually raised the last but one match, so he lost

Comment: "The player who takes the last match loses the game."

Comment: @ScottHunter ohhhh, it was a typo, I was sure I wrote the llast but one. I have already edited

Comment: Please explain what "The player who takes the last but one loses the game" means.  As an example of my confusion, if there are 3 matches & it is the computer's turn, why can't the computer just take all 3 to win?

Comment: @ScottHunter the gain depends not so much on how many matches the computer takes, but on how many it leaves for the user. For example, if there are 3 matches on the table and the computer has to choose, it can only win by choosing one match, because the last but one (second from the end) remains for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick analysis:

```
matches23(N, T) :-
    between(1, 23, N),
    matches23_(N, T).

matches23_(N, T) :-
    % My move
    take_matches(N, T, N0),
    % Opponent's move, ensuring opponent cannot win
    \+ matches23_(N0, _).

take_matches(N, T, N0) :-
    between(1, 3, T),
    N0 is N - T,
    % Leave at least 1 remaining
    N0 @>= 1.
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- findall(N-T, matches23(N, T), Ps).
Ps = [2-1, 3-2, 4-3, 6-1, 7-2, 8-3, 10-1, 11-2, 12-3, 
      14-1, 15-2, 16-3, 18-1, 19-2, 20-3, 22-1, 23-2].
```

So, start the 23 game by removing 2 matches, and you have a guaranteed win if you follow the other steps :-)

Comment: I don't think you understand what I need or I don't understand what you meant by this code. The point is that you need to change the strategy of the computer so that it always wins the player. I would be grateful if you could adapt it directly in my code, because I don't know very advanced prolog

Comment: "The point is that you need to change the strategy of the computer so that it always wins the player" - that is nonsense. I've given you the winning moves.

Comment: Why is this nonsense?

Comment: To repeat, I've given you the winning moves - and the code to create them. These winning moves apply equally to the player or the opponent.

Comment: "if you could adapt it directly in my code" - I've given you a winning engine, with the essential inputs and outputs, so it's your job to adapt your code to mine, not for me to adapt my code to yours. If you're unable to do that, I suggest raising a separate question.

Comment: UPD. I analyzed your code a bit and integrated it into my program. Yes, it works as I intended. Thanks